# Can't login to Firebase after I added Key restriction

Tags: android, firebase, error-handling, firebase-authentication

I use this code to login to Firebase:

```
mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(txtEmail.getText().toString().trim(),
    txtPassword.getText().toString().trim())
    .addOnSuccessListener(((ActivitySplash) mContext), authResult -> {
            /// do something
    })
    .addOnFailureListener(((ActivitySplash) mContext), e -> {
           /// do something else
    });
```

All was perfect until I have added the package name and SHA-1 signing-certificate fingerprint to restrict key usage just by my application. After I did this I can't login anymore. If I remove restrictions all work perfectly again. Suggestions?

Comment: When we register the android app in Firebase, we will be providing the package name and SHA certificate(optional), In case if any of these two then you might need to update the corresponding project in firebase and download the updated google-service.json and place it in your root directory of the project. Try and let me know if it works

Comment: @VaikundamRaghul I'd probably post your comment as an answer, as failing to download/use the updated `google-services.json` is indeed a common cause of this problem.

Comment: Can you accept the answer if it benefits you, it will help others for their ease

Comment: I have same key in json, google_map_key and google crash api. The app work how is expected until I try to restrict usage of my key just to my application. When activate restriction the app can't login to firebase. If I remove restriction the applciation work again instantly.

Answer (score 0):

When we register the android app in Firebase, we will be providing the package name and SHA certificate(optional), In case if any of these two then you might need to update the corresponding project in firebase and download the updated google-service.json and place it in your root directory of the project

Comment: I don't register a new app. I use that key for two years. I just want to limit usage to my app.

Comment: Wouldn't you have registered your application when you first create the project in firebase?

Comment: Is already registered by two years.  Now I just want to limit key usage to my app because google added billing for some API usage. And don't want to pay for someone else usage. If read my code I talk about user login and not my app registration (mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword).